# websocket only responding when I set breakpoints

Tags: websocket

I have a process using the standard websocket code.  When the socket opens I want to send a message. I want to then listen to response from the socket.  If I place debug breakpoints in chrome's inspector it seems to wait long enough to get the response. If I remove the breakpoints the `onmessage` function never gets called.  Does anyone see if I'm missing anything?

```
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);

var message = {};
message.messageType = 'db_request';
message.value = 'lanes';

websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
    $log.debug('message received');
    scope.lanes = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    scope.$apply();
}

websocket.onopen = function () {
    $log.debug('open');
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    $log.debug('sent');
}
```

In my console, I see the `sent` message. And in the logging of the service I see a response...

Comment: As a rule of thumb - this is a classic indicator of a race condition.

Comment: how might you solve such classic case? ;) have an article to read?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a silver bullet solution to race conditions. I gave an upvote though. Also, you might want to end the serverside code receiving this.

Comment: end it after receiving the message?

Comment: Autocorrect fail, sorry, "add" the serverside code - so we can see what's going there.

Comment: Found out the server side might not have added me to the list of subscribers to respond to before it responds with the request I sent